# Using networkx to show connection between columns Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

How do I use networkx to show the connection between the values in df?

Example of the values in my df

```
      | login  | device | countrycode | ... |
  0   |   l1   |   d1   |     US      | ... |
  1   |   l2   |   d1   |     US      | ... |
  2   |   l3   |   d1   |     US      | ... |
  3   |   l4   |   d2   |     RU      | ... | 
  4   |   l5   |   d3   |     EU      | ... |
  5   |   l5   |   d1   |     US      | ... |
```

What I want in an output is to show a connection between the device and the login where d1 has over 3 logins connected to it.

[image: Something like this]

I've tried to use networkx by reading the documentation and searching on the different ways on how to do it but I'm not sure how to make it work and to show the connections.

Comment: [This post](https://towardsdatascience.com/from-dataframe-to-network-graph-bbb35c8ab675) might help you.